# Shift row vector values

Tags: matlab

How can I shift the entries of a vector `c` like this:

```
c = [1; 2; 0];
x = [1; 2; 3];

y(1:3) = rightshift(c', 0:2) * x;

% Should produce:
% y(1) = [1; 2; 0]' * x; 
% y(2) = [0; 1; 2]' * x; 
% y(3) = [0; 0; 1]' * x;
```

to produce the output vector `y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`toeplitz`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html) -

```
N = numel(c);
y = triu(toeplitz(c,0:N-1).')*x
```

Or with `mod & bsxfun` -

```
N = numel(c)
y = triu(c((mod(bsxfun(@minus,[0:N-1]',0:N-1),N)+1).'))*x
```

Or with just `bsxfun` -

```
N = numel(c);
c_ext = [zeros(N-1,1) ; c(:)]
y = c_ext(bsxfun(@plus,[N:-1:1]',[0:N-1]))*x
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I really tried but I couldn't think that up myself ^^

Comment: @StefanFalk No problem really!

Comment: Could it be that `toeplitz(c,0:N-1)` should be `toeplitz(c,1:N)` because if I start at `0` I am getting the warning: "*Warning: First element of input column does not match first element of input row. Column wins diagonal conflict.*" but starting from `1` works flawless.

Comment: @StefanFalk I think you can ignore that *warning*. You would get that warning with `toeplitz(c,1:N)` too when you have other elements in `c` for example if `c = [8 ;4 ;5]`.

Answer (score 1):

That's essentially a convolution:

```
y = conv(c(end:-1:1), x);
y = y(end-numel(c)+1:end);
```

Comment: This answer is also perfectly fine. But (for some reason) we weren't allowed to use `convmtx()`, `conv()` and `for`-loops in order to do that. Got to say that this question came from an assignment.